# Which .NET Service Bus to migrate to Azure

Tags: azure, servicebus

I need to develop a web app which needs to 'talk' to lots of other apps/api's as well as implementing real time notifications to users and standard Publish/Subscribe type functionality.

The client wants to develop on-premises and then migrate to Azure in the near(ish) future. Which .NET Service Bus is best suited for this requirement?

Comment: Tool/framework recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I would remove the phrase "best suited" from the question.  Then it becomes a concrete question with a concrete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your short answer is "Windows Service Bus 1.1".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282152.aspx

Ideally, you're going to write the same code and can deploy to either.

That does not mean there are no differences.  Namely "security".  Using " Shared Access Secrets" will be safe in both worlds.

Below are 2 URL's to help.

***Azure Queues and Service Bus queues - compared and contrasted***

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted/

***Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 Overview***

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn282142.aspx

> In both Microsoft Azure and Windows Server, Service Bus requires
>   access tokens for authorizing access to its messaging entities. Both
>   share the Shared Access Secrets (SAS) authentication scheme for
>   Service Bus namespaces as well as entities (queues and topics).
>
> However, in Windows Azure, Service Bus also supports the Microsoft
>   Azure Active Directory Access Control (also known as Access Control
>   Service or ACS), which is not available on Windows Server.
>
> However, on
>   Windows Server, Service Bus supports Windows integrated authentication
>   (domain joined users and Active Directory user groups), which are not
>   available in Azure.